# Xcode 14 UI test recorder button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcode14

So I was trying to create some UI tests and found that the UI record button was no longer at the place near the break point button. Does anyone know where I can find it, or if I failed to turn on anything?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can capture UI by going Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy

Also make sure you have those in your scheme enabled
[image]

Click Scheme -> Edit -> Test -> Info  then enable debug executable
another thing might help click on Options -> then enable capture screenshots automatically.

Comment: Capture View Hierarchy is grayed out for me, do you happen to know why?

Comment: enable from scheme image above